# How do I separate a string with different (& repeated) separators into multiple columns?

Tags: r, dplyr

I am having difficulty separating data in one column into multiple columns -- the data has multiple separators. I checked the stackoverflow solutions but could not find one that matched my situation.

**Input**
[image]

**My attempt**

```
df %>%
  separate(col = game, into = c("year", "day", "month", "monthday", "site", "team", "decision", "runs1", "runs2", "pitcher"), sep = "[. ,-]", remove = TRUE)
```

**Desired output (see input image)**

**Dput**

```
structure(list(game = c("2021. Mon, Apr 5 at PHI L (3-5)#", "2020. Fri, Jul 24 vs ATL W (1-0)", 
"2019. Thu, Mar 28 at WSN W (2-0)", "2018. Thu, Mar 29 vs STL W (9-4)", 
"2017. Mon, Apr 3 vs ATL W (6-0)"), pitcher = c("deGrom", "deGrom", 
"deGrom", "Syndergaard", "Syndergaard")), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I would prefer a `dplyr` result but am open to others.

Comment: To whomever closed my post: The post that you said answers my question does not. It is associated with my post, but in that post's answer, it begins with "'sep' needs to be a single character value representing a regular expression." That answer, today, is not correct. In functions such as separate, the `sep` argument now can have multiple values. Responses to my post show how. Therefore, I believe that my post should be reopened. In addition, I never received your private feedback. Where can I find it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

many good answers, one other variation below

```
#replace all punctuation with a space then seperate
  df %>% 
    mutate(game=str_replace_all(game,"[:punct:]"," ")) %>% 
    separate(col = game,into = c("year", "day", "month", "monthday", "site", "team", "decision", "runs1", "runs2"))
```

Comment: Your solution has a missing `pitcher` column

Comment: yes, sorry, because I had "pitcher" in the into columns. I edited it to remove it.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if that is any existing function that allows you to separate using multiple separator, therefore I just substituted all separator into `@` for `separate` to work.

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  mutate(game = gsub("\\.\\s|,\\s|\\s+|-", "@", game) %>% 
           gsub("\\(|\\)|#", "", .)) %>% 
  separate(game, 
           into = c("year", "day", "month", "monthday", "site", "team", "decision", "runs1", "runs2"), 
           sep = "@")

# A tibble: 5 × 10
  year  day   month monthday site  team  decision runs1 runs2 pitcher    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>      
1 2021  Mon   Apr   5        at    PHI   L        3     5     deGrom     
2 2020  Fri   Jul   24       vs    ATL   W        1     0     deGrom     
3 2019  Thu   Mar   28       at    WSN   W        2     0     deGrom     
4 2018  Thu   Mar   29       vs    STL   W        9     4     Syndergaard
5 2017  Mon   Apr   3        vs    ATL   W        6     0     Syndergaard
```

Answer (score 2):

We may use `extract` which can be used to capture substring in group

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
  extract(game, into = c("year", "day", "month", "monthday", "site",
     "team", "decision", "runs1", "runs2"), 
    "^(\\d{4})\\.\\s+(\\w+),\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\d+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+(\\w+)\\s+\\((\\d+)-(\\d+)\\).*", convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 10
   year day   month monthday site  team  decision runs1 runs2 pitcher    
  <int> <chr> <chr>    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int> <int> <chr>      
1  2021 Mon   Apr          5 at    PHI   L            3     5 deGrom     
2  2020 Fri   Jul         24 vs    ATL   W            1     0 deGrom     
3  2019 Thu   Mar         28 at    WSN   W            2     0 deGrom     
4  2018 Thu   Mar         29 vs    STL   W            9     4 Syndergaard
5  2017 Mon   Apr          3 vs    ATL   W            6     0 Syndergaard
```

---

or with `separate`

```
df %>% 
  separate(col = game, into = c("year", "day", "month", "monthday", 
    "site", "team", "decision", "runs1", "runs2"),
     sep = "\\s*[.,\\(\\)-]\\s*|\\s+", remove = TRUE, convert = TRUE)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 5 × 10
   year day   month monthday site  team  decision runs1 runs2 pitcher    
  <int> <chr> <chr>    <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <int> <int> <chr>      
1  2021 Mon   Apr          5 at    PHI   L            3     5 deGrom     
2  2020 Fri   Jul         24 vs    ATL   W            1     0 deGrom     
3  2019 Thu   Mar         28 at    WSN   W            2     0 deGrom     
4  2018 Thu   Mar         29 vs    STL   W            9     4 Syndergaard
5  2017 Mon   Apr          3 vs    ATL   W            6     0 Syndergaard
```

Comment: nice regex skills. Any website or course you recommend?

Comment: @alejandro_hagan thanks. you can check [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).   I haven't taken any course for that, but when I get some doubts, i check links like that one

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to perform the clean-up in steps:

```
temp <- df %>%
   separate(col = game, into = c("year", "day", "month", "monthday", "site", "team", "decision", "runs1"), sep = " ", remove = TRUE)

#remove the decimal
temp$year<- as.integer(temp$year)
#remove the comma after the day
temp$day <- gsub(",", "", temp$day)

#clean up and split the runs column
temp$runs1<- gsub( ".+(\\d+)-(\\d+).+", "\\1 \\2", temp$runs1)
answer <-temp %>% separate(col = runs1, into = c("runs1", "runs2"), sep = " ", remove = TRUE)
```

A little longer but easier to debug in the future.

Answer (score 2):

This could be another approach:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>%
  mutate(game2 = strsplit(game, split = "\\.\\s|,\\s|\\s", perl = TRUE)) %>%
  unnest_wider(game2) %>%
  rename_with(., ~ str_replace(., "(\\.){3}\\d", 
                               c("year", "day", "month", "monthday", "site", "team", "decision", "runs1")), !c(game, pitcher)) %>%
  extract(runs1, c('runs1', 'runs2'), regex = "^.(\\d+).*(\\d+).*") %>%
  select(!game) %>%
  relocate(pitcher, .after = last_col())

# A tibble: 5 x 10
  year  day   month monthday site  team  decision runs1 runs2 pitcher    
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>    <chr> <chr> <chr>      
1 2021  Mon   Apr   5        at    PHI   L        3     5     deGrom     
2 2020  Fri   Jul   24       vs    ATL   W        1     0     deGrom     
3 2019  Thu   Mar   28       at    WSN   W        2     0     deGrom     
4 2018  Thu   Mar   29       vs    STL   W        9     4     Syndergaard
5 2017  Mon   Apr   3        vs    ATL   W        6     0     Syndergaard
```